# Why are my h1 tagged strings smaller than my h2 tagged strings?

Tags: html, css

This odd thing is happening. I am not sure if it is bad practice, but I figured it would give me consistent sizes between the strings in the html. I have a title in `<h1>` and subsections of information in `<h2>` and anything more as `<h3>`. My understanding is that `<h1>` is the largest and h6 is the smallest. I tested this on firefox and chrome. There is only one css and only h1 effects that code. I even took the css code out and the underline. Anyway, I did some test strings:

[image]

Mind you, I have some css that is supposed to make the h1 tags underline.

```css
 h1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<h2>test</h2>
<h3>test</h3>
<h4>test</h4>
<h5>test</h5>
<h6>test</h6>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referencing any other css files that may be overriding the style?

Comment: There could be some other CSS file that modifies your H1 tag size.

Comment: it's not really easy to say if you're not publishing the HTML/CSS. But i can only recommend you to use the dev-console of firefox/chrome. Shortcut is F12. By clicking on Inspect you're able to see all the css thats applied there.

Comment: If you remove `underline` from `h1`,what will happen?

Comment: @HelloNewWorld The underline goes away but the size stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is smaller because 1.17em < 1.5em

As you could see, the h1 applied style is 1.17em, applied by a stylesheet (I think in your case is chrome's defaults). and the h2 has 1.5em.

**Fixes:**

You need to define the size at your own stylesheet http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

**Note:**
h1, h2, h3 are used more than just to give sizes. They are heading tags, denoting importance of some words/phrases on the html content.

You can read more about the H tags here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Comment: I think I figured out the cause. I had an incorrectly closed </nav>. I do not understand why that would cause my h1 to change size.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that your css has been over-ridden by another set of rules (perhaps local browser rules).

I would suggest that you first test in another browser to see i fit changes, 
and then if that does not help, use something like **Chrome's Developer Tools** or **Firebug** to see *where* the H1 definition is coming from.

Comment: I added a screenshot.